# How to extend the HashSet in Java?

Tags: java, hashset

Let's say I have a `CategoryKey` class:

```
public class CategoryKey {
    public int layer;
    public int parent;
    public int child;
}
```

I try to put many instances of it within a `Set`, but as we know `HashSet` is not suitable to store instances of custom classes. So how can I extend the java class `HashSet` to meet my requirement? Or how can I create a new class implementing interface `Set` to solve the same problem?

Comment: "HashSet is not suitable for store instances of customed class" Why not?

Comment: What do you mean "as we know"? `HashSet` is very suitable for storing instances of any object that has `.hashCode()` and `.equals()` properly implemented.

Comment: Please cover my tutorial on [Internal life of HashSet](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashset-in-java.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but as we know HashSet is not suitable for store instances of customed class

Yes it is, so long as you write your class appropriate. In particular:

- You should override `equals()` and `hashCode()`
- You should make your type immutable
- You shouldn't use public fields

For example:

```
public final class CategoryKey {
  private final int layer;
  private final int parent;
  private final int child;

  public CategoryKey(int layer, int parent, int child) {
    this.layer = layer;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.child = child;
  }

  public int getLayer() {
    return layer;
  }

  public int getParent() {
    return parent;
  }

  public int getChild() {
    return child;
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof CategoryKey)) {
      return false;
    }
    CategoryKey otherKey = (CategoryKey) other;
    return layer == otherKey.layer
      && parent == otherKey.parent
      && child == otherKey.child;
  }

  @Override public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 23;
    hash = hash * 31 + layer;
    hash = hash * 31 + parent;
    hash = hash * 31 + child;
    return hash;
  }
}
```

Comment: A better way is to use HashBuilder and EqualsBuilder from [apache-commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html). The reflection based method is quite concise and wouldn't require frequent updates.

Comment: That said, reflection is slow.  Do it Jon's way.

Comment: I just read the related [material](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html) and wonder whether the 31 can be replaced with other prime number? @Jon Skeet

Comment: @jerry_sjtu: It can, but multiplying by 31 can be optimised to a shift and subtract. Basically I do what Josh Bloch tells me :)

Answer (score 2):

Why is HashSet not suitable to store instances of custom classes?

As long as your class has a proper implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Override `equals` and `hashCode` method of `CategoryKey` to provide unique instance in `Set`

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element.

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: Not exactly, you need to override the hashCode as well.